# How to have Linux ls command show second in time stamp

Tags: linux, ls

Something annoying about `ls -l` command is it shows only hour and minute for a file(like 08:30). How can I see the second portion(like 08:30:44)?

`man 1 ls` and search for 'second' does not give any clue.

Comment: These days `ls -l` shows second...for even higher granularity see some of the answers here... :")

Comment: @rogerdpack, not for me (bash)

Comment: And for old files it shows the year, and not either the hour or minute!

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Does your version of ls support the `--time-style` option?  If so:

```
ls -la --time-style=full-iso blah

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 2011-11-08 18:02:08.954092000 -0700 blah
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, even on a old Mandrake Linux 10.0 from year 2005. --full-time OK as well.

Comment: or "ls -ale" (only this worked for me on an older linux distro)

Comment: Mac OSX equivalent: `ls -lT`

Comment: What is the difference between `--time-style=full` and `--time-style=full-iso`?

Comment: @neverMind9 That's the same. You can even use `--time-style=f` for the same effect. `full-iso` is the full name, other unambiguous short names can also be used. *The TIME_STYLE argument can be full-iso, long-iso, iso, locale, or +FORMAT.*

Comment: Now we can clearly see that after all these years ssh/sshfs STILL doesn't support sub-second time stamps!  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=971645

Answer (score 151):

The more simple way is:

```
ls --full-time
```

which is equal to

```
ls -l --time-style=full-iso
```

If you want to show entries as hidden files starting with `.`, add `-a`:

```
ls --full-time -a
```

Comment: What is the difference between `--time-style=full` and `--time-style=full-iso`?

Comment: @neverMind9 There is no difference. The value is internaly expanded from `full` to `full-iso`. Same happens e.g. to `f`. It does not work for `l` or `lo`, because they could be `long-iso` or `locale`. But `lon` will expand to `long-iso`

Answer (score 52):

For OS X, it looks like the best you get is:

```
ls -l -T
```

From the `ls(1)` manpage on 10.10.5:

> **-T** When used with the -l (lowercase letter ``ell'') option, display complete time information for the file, including month, day, hour, minute, second, and year.

Comment: Or like this: `ls -lT`.

Comment: this also works in Windows/Ubuntu

Comment: You may want to take a closer look at that man page, specifically the `-D` option which was inherited from BSD and has been there forever.

Answer (score 29):

An alternative to the approved answer - you can use a custom format like in the date command if "--time-style=full-iso" output is too detailed for you:

```
ls -l --time-style=+"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S" blah
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 03 2014 01:13:01 blah
```

Answer (score 5):

On BusyBox systems, `ls -e` works fine!

Comment: Which version of GNU coreutils do you use? With 8.20 I don't have this parameter.

Comment: Version please :)

Comment: When using GNU coreutils 8.22 `ls` there is no `-e` option. I suspect the version of `ls` you have is Darwin based.

Comment: BusyBox. Embedded Linuxes. Yes. Try `-e` if these other (GNU based) flags fail.

Comment: Just for information, this also works with BusyBox on Android.

Answer (score 3):

For BSD systems including FreeBSD and macOS, it would be:

```sh
ls -la -D '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
```